# What is the next image?

Tags: pattern, visual

[image]

## Which image (1-5) could replace the blank tile?

Hints:

1.

> Neighbours are important

2.

> Overlapping

3.

> The lines

4.

> Two at a time...

Big one.

> Criss crossing lines after overlapping each pair of images

Comment: Sorry for my bad drawing with the numbers

Comment: Is this a sequence, a set that satisfies a property, or do you not want to say?

Comment: @greenturtle3141, I'll say this, you can't just look at individual tiles to work out the answer

Comment: Add more hints!

Comment: @TylerJohnson, one a day...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, I'm prone to operate with the understanding that this is resolved sequentially in some form given that the question is "What is the _next_ image". Basically, that these boxes as they are layed out are in some way ordered. You know, just thinking out loud here.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, has it something to do with the angles formed in each shape? However 3rd and 5th are throwing me off from thinking on that line.

Comment: 3rd hint is hilarious!

Comment: I first thing I did was to try overlapping... But nu :c

Comment: Is the rule something like: When overlapped in pairs, each line in the previous picture is intersected by a line? It doesn't work for the first and last two though...

Comment: I think that the picture needs to be redone. I tried to overlap the pictures, but the picture is so full of artifacts, and the images are so irregular, that I can't figure out how they're supposed to line up. I can tell that you made the graphics yourself, but they really need to be more uniform.

Comment: Can we have another hint ._.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 sure, I want this solved too

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Somehow, I expected the last hint to have 8 words ;). Nevertheless, regarding all hints: BTDTGTT and still no idea.

Comment: If all the points of intersections are overlaid, I think we can safely say that this represents Josh Donaldson's hitting zone chart through the first two games of the ALCS.

Comment: @John, umm. Its a lot simpler than that, go with dan russel's answer for now

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, got too much baseball on the brain!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Image 4**, because of two observations:
>  - within a single image, there are no crossed lines (T's are okay)
>  - in all pairwise overlaps, no line in one image is crossed twice by the other image
>
>  Image 4 is the only option that meets both criteria. (3 and 5 cross themselves, and 1, 2, 3 cause double-crossings in the overlap.)

Comment: ...I can rest at peace... Well done! I'll award the bounty soon, but for now enjoy the accept!

Comment: "T's are okay" - Well, all intersection angles are okay, just not an intersection that appears to be a pass-through.

Comment: @John Yes, that is what I meant. 'T' was the most concise way to express that. The focus is less on the specific angle, and more on the fact that the lines touch, but do not cross. I could have used 'Y', but 'T' is already used to describe topology (e.g. road intersections).

Comment: @Phlarx, I know you knew. Just clarifying for example that possible solution 5 is not say, a down arrow pointed at a right angle, but that it's specifically a 'cross' with a line going up. Good job by the way!! +1.

Answer (score 2):

Since the hints seem to point to

> pairwise overlaps, here's a diagram to show what that looks like.  Still don't know what the answer is, though.
>
>  [image]

Comment: That is a very good start! Just what I was looking for. Now check the other hints...

Comment: The big hint wants intersections... Is it not that each line in one picture intersects another in the second? Because it doesn't work for the first and last two...

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Yeah, it did seem like that would be possible except for the first and last pairs.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 It almost looks like at least one intersection location is preserved in each successive pair, except for the last one.

Comment: Intersection location preservation seems almost correct except for that last pair.

Comment: You are so close!

Answer (score 0):

> **4**. The result of the ex-triangle is a side rearrangement. Only 4 complies with that. Then sides get to multiply and reduce until they get to another triangle.

Comment: Afraid not good effort though

Comment: I don't get what you mean in your answer.

Comment: There is no simpler rule than this one.

Comment: If it's so simple can you please clarify your answer? What and where is this extriangle?

Comment: The patter for this is X R R R - D C U X , there fore after that triangle a line rearrangement (R) must happen. Since for the first R position the lines do not intersect, only 4 will comply with the pattern and respect that.

Comment: What is X and the other letters... What do you mean by line rearrangement... What do you mean by first R... You really need to explain as if I'm an idiot and use pictures because I'm not getting the logic here.

Comment: X is the initial and final state of the object. R are the line rearrangements (meaning lines change positions). The D and C can be ignored (square and open square), since they are a step that does not affect the result as far as the figure string goes. Wish I could represent this in 3D, would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

My Guess,

> My Answer is  **5**.
>  Above Totally 9 Images, So I splited into 3 section.
>  **3rd** image have  **3 lines**,
>  **6th** image have **4 lines** and
>  so, **9th** image(blank) should have 5 lines.
>  Answer Option Images Have only one **Five Line** Image that is 5th image.so, MY Answer is 5 image could replace blank(**9th**) one.

Comment: Sorry nice try, but afraid not

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me.  Would you care to explain your answer in clear language?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's:

> 1. Because there are multiple reflections, especially given the last clue. I can't figure the reasoning, but early on I saw that 6 & 7 merged resulted in a common **copy** icon. After overlapping *and* tilting 3 & 4, there's a double X shape. That leaves 1, 2, & 5 orphaned in this explanation.

Comment: I'm afraid that was just a coincidence... nice try though

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, Wahh... wahhh... (sad horn)... I'll take another look later.